PowerShell, how to press a button on a web form
The page https://schneegans.de/windows/unattend-generator is a form that lets you define what will be in the autounatted.xml to use with automated installations of Windows, and results in a URL that contains all of these options. Now that I have exactly what I want from the options in the form, I want to then press the Download file button that is on the form so that I can get the autounattend.xml onto my system. I've been trying the below without success. Maybe I am using the wrong approach to collect this XML file?
How can I use this URL and trigger the Download file button on this page (or any other way in PowerShell that I can collect the relevant XML data for the autounattend.xml)?
# URL of the page
$url = "https://schneegans.de/windows/unattend-generator/?LanguageMode=Unattended&UILanguage=en-US&UserLocale=en-GB&KeyboardLayout=0809%3A00000809&GeoLocation=242&ProcessorArchitecture=amd64&ComputerNameMode=Custom&ComputerName=Win10&TimeZoneMode=Implicit&PartitionMode=Unattended&PartitionLayout=GPT&EspSize=300&RecoveryMode=Partition&RecoverySize=600&WindowsEditionMode=Unattended&WindowsEdition=pro&UserAccountMode=Unattended&AccountName0=Boss&AccountPassword0=boss&AccountGroup0=Administrators&AccountName1=User&AccountPassword1=user&AccountGroup1=Users&AccountName2=&AccountName3=&AccountName4=&AutoLogonMode=Own&PasswordExpirationMode=Default&LockoutMode=Default&DisableSystemRestore=true&EnableLongPaths=true&EnableRemoteDesktop=true&HardenSystemDriveAcl=true&AllowPowerShellScripts=true&DisableLastAccess=true&NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers=true&TurnOffSystemSounds=true&DisableAppSuggestions=true&ProcessAudit=true&ProcessAuditCommandLine=true&WifiMode=Skip&ExpressSettings=DisableAll&SystemScript0=&SystemScriptType0=Cmd&SystemScript1=&SystemScriptType1=Ps1&SystemScript2=&SystemScriptType2=Reg&SystemScript3=&SystemScriptType3=Vbs&DefaultUserScript0=&DefaultUserScriptType0=Reg&FirstLogonScript0=&FirstLogonScriptType0=Cmd&FirstLogonScript1=&FirstLogonScriptType1=Ps1&FirstLogonScript2=&FirstLogonScriptType2=Reg&FirstLogonScript3=&FirstLogonScriptType3=Vbs&UserOnceScript0=&UserOnceScriptType0=Cmd&UserOnceScript1=&UserOnceScriptType1=Ps1&UserOnceScript2=&UserOnceScriptType2=Reg&UserOnceScript3=&UserOnceScriptType3=Vbs&WdacMode=Skip"

try {
    # Send request to the page
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url

    # Parse the HTML response
    $html = $response.ParsedHtml

    # Find the download button element
    $downloadButton = $html.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary')

    if ($downloadButton -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "Download button not found."
    }

    # Extract the download link
    $downloadLink = $downloadButton.getAttribute('href')

    # Download the file
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadLink -OutFile "autounattend.xml"
    Write-Host "File downloaded successfully."
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Error occurred: $_"
}


Do you need to download it dynamically? Is there a reason you can't just generate it manually as a one-off step, save it as an xml file (or embed it as a string in your script) and use that as a template in your script? Also, if you use the "view file" button at the very bottom of the page it will take you to a url with the appropriate querystring in it - you could probably just construct that url and querystring in your code  and use invoke-restmethod on that to get the unattend.xml content rather than POST the "download file" form...

You can open the debugger tools in your browser (using F12) to check which url is being hit and which data is posted (on the "network" tab). Chrome and Firefox even have a "copy to Powershell" option which will generate the PS code for you including headers and cookies

These are both things that I didn't know were possible, and great (I knew F12, but didn't know Chrome and Firefox have a "Copy to PowerShell" option!). I don't need to press the button and would happily use the output from "View file", that's a good idea. I know that I can do things like (invoke-webrequest $url).RawContent to see everything on the page, but that's probably a bit primitive, do you have a better / more precise method that will extract the XML more precisely with invoke-restmethod?

You are reaching the limitations of what can be accomplished using PowerShell. If you find yourself needing to interact with DOM elements, then you should be using JavaScript, which is designed for this exact purpose.

No need for clicking a button – just use the view or download actions:
$url = 'https://schneegans.de/windows/unattend-generator/view/?LanguageMode=...';
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile "$env:TEMP\autounattend.xml";

Source: I am the author of that service.
